# Compile error when running a docker script in Jenkins build

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins

I have been working through the docker book and I am now learning about CI. I tried to run this script within the execute shell of my build:

```
# Build the image to be used for this job.
IMAGE=$(sudo docker build . | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF }') 
# Build the directory to be mounted into Docker.
MNT="$WORKSPACE/.."
# Execute the build inside Docker.
CONTAINER=$(sudo docker run -d -v $MNT:/opt/project/ $IMAGE /bin/ bash -c 'cd /opt/project/workspace; rake spec')
# Attach to the container so that we can see the output.
   sudo docker attach $CONTAINER
# Get its exit code as soon as the container stops.
RC=$(sudo docker wait $CONTAINER)
# Delete the container we've just used.
   sudo docker rm $CONTAINER
# Exit with the same value as that with which the process exited.
exit $RC
```

Running this script ends in the build failing. It shows these two errors:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`
and 
`sudo docker run -d -v /private/var/jenkins_home/jobs/${Docker_test_job}/workspace/..:/opt/project/ /bin/ bash -c cd /opt/project/workspace; rake spec
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
+ CONTAINER=
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE`

I don't understand how to fix it as I've been following the instructions in the book. I tried using $PWD to try and fix my issue but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actaully the jenkins user does not have the permission to run docker command. To do this, add your jenkins user to the docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Then restart your jenkins server to refresh the group.
Please  be informed that ther is a warning "The docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. For details on how this impacts security in your system."

Comment: where do I run this command? I tried it in terminal(MacOS) and it says user mod command not found. Sorry, I probably should've mentioned that I was working on Mac before.

Comment: Please check this one to add user to group in mac https://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line/214311